# converting string to titlecase in Python

Tags: python

I would like to convert the following string in Python to titlecase:

`sr = "MURANG'A"`

`sr.title()` gives `"Murang'A"`, but I would like `"Murang'a"`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub("([a-z])([^\s]*)",lambda m:m.group(1).upper()+m.group(2),sr)
```

would probably give you what you want ... but there is a famous story about having one problem and thinking "I know ill use regex to solve it"

```
>>> sr = "bazing'a marz'a"
>>> re.sub("([a-z])([^\s]*)",lambda m:m.group(1).upper()+m.group(2),sr)
"Bazing'a Marz'a"
```